# Is the derivative of a big-O class the same as the big-O class of the derivative?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Basically, for every function $f(x) \in O(g(x))$, is $f'(x) \in O(g'(x))$?

Comment: The important thing is that $O$ cares about global behavior, how fast the function grows as $x \to \infty$.  The derivative cares about local behavior, and can be very large if the function is highly oscillatory, without the function increasing rapidly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\sin(x^3)$. Then, certainly $g\in O(f)$, but $f'(x)=1$, and $g'(x)=3x^2\cos(x^3)$ and $\displaystyle \limsup_{x\to\infty} 3x^2\cos(x^3)=\infty$.

Comment: Okay, so the follow-up here is, what are the classes of functions called where this is true? I'm pretty sure polynomials and exponentials do this.

Comment: You never followed up on OP's comment.  I'm wondering the same thing, 3.5 years later.